# Change Color of Selected Anchors for Sections on Site NO JAVASCRIPT

Tags: html, css, anchor, sections

So I've got some section anchors inside a fixed header. I wanted to see if there's any css property/trick/hack I'm not aware of that will allow me to have the selected section anchor's color change when you select it, and obviously change back to the regular style when you select another section. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but **I cannot use javascript** - only css. It's all on a one-page site, so it's not like I'm changing the color on a new page.

```
<header>
<ul>
<li><a href="#one">○</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">○</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">○</a></li>
<li><a href="#four">○</a></li>
<li><a href="#five">○</a></li>
</ul>
<header>
```

**EDIT** : A new approach.
After some research I decided to play around with the :focus feature of buttons.

Here's what I got:

**HTML**

```
<button href="one" class="circle">○</button>
<button href="two" class="circle">○</button>
<button href="three" class="circle">○</button>
<button href="four" class="circle">○</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.circle:focus {
    color: red;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
}
```

I thought I could use buttons as anchor tags... fail.

Comment: You could use the checkboxes trick... But you'll save yourself a lot of time using JavaScript instead.

Comment: Are you using any kind of single page application structure (e.g., Angular or React)?

Comment: I know it's way easier to use JavaScript, and no I'm not using any application structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :focus.

```
a:focus { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Only while the anchor is focused. If the user presses Tab, it will no longer have focus (and therefore not have the background color), even though the page is at the anchor previously clicked.

Comment: @HereticMonkey true, but better than just "no" for an answer :) This is the best possible solution without the obvious JavaScript, which Zach said he can't use.

Comment: Not without the caveat that it doesn't actually do what the OP wants. Also, if you read the duplicate I posted, you can use `:target`. Please don't change your answer to `:target` though.

Comment: @Brad ... you know? You're right. It's only if the element is the target of the fragment identifier, not the href. I'll retract my close vote. Still doesn't make this answer any better :)

Comment: I'm not as familiar with css conditionals, but I'll take a bit to learn and see if there's any way to use them. :focus and :target do not work. Perhaps there's something related to visibility.